# Смена языка HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! можете пожалуйста подсказать как сделать так, чтобы при выборе языка(флага), флаг который стоит изначально менялся на тот, который выбрали.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 135px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(37, 210, 127, 0.94);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.navigation {
  height: 135px;
}

.cities {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 6%;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.round {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  margin-left: 213px;
  top: 25px;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.dollarSign {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  /* identical to box height */
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoText {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 39px;
  width: 395px;
  height: 59px;
  color: white;
}

.logoName {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 59px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoName:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  background-origin: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  transition: 1s;
}

.logoName:not(:hover) {
  transition: 1s;
}

.selected-lang {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.selected-lang:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/MCXYQD1/russia.png);
}

.triangle {
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 116px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-top: 7px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 6.5px;
}

.lang-menu {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.languages {
  position: absolute;
  left: 803.5px;
  top: 50px;
}

.lang-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 108px;
  padding-right: 38px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3s);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.lang-menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: 34px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.lang-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 108px;
}

.lang-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.lang-menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.lang-menu:hover ul {
  transition: 1s;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Предприниматели Казахстана</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="navigation">
      <img src="images/Cities.png" alt="Cities" class="cities" />
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="round">
          <p class="dollarSign">$</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logoText">
          <p class="logoName">ENTERPRENEUR.KZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="languages">
        <div class="lang-menu">
          <div class="selected-lang">
            Язык:
            <div class="triangle"></div>
          </div>
          <ul class="bgLang">
            <li>
              <a><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SyxxBx8/kazakhstan.png" alt="KZ" width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rbcBCtd/united-kingdom.png" alt="UK" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Конец navigation -->
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ, надеюсь, вам поможет,
Если хотите еще что-то, пожалуйста уточните вопрос

```js
const ru = 'https://i.ibb.co/MCXYQD1/russia.png'
const KZ = 'https://i.ibb.co/SyxxBx8/kazakhstan.png'
const UK = 'https://i.ibb.co/rbcBCtd/united-kingdom.png'

const imgPlace = document.querySelector('.selected-lang-img')

const langImgs = document.querySelectorAll('ul.bgLang li img')
langImgs.forEach(img => {
        img.addEventListener('click', e => {
            let last = e.target.src
            let next = imgPlace.src
            imgPlace.src = last
            e.target.src = next
    })
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 135px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(37, 210, 127, 0.94);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.navigation {
  height: 135px;
}

.cities {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 6%;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.round {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  margin-left: 213px;
  top: 25px;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.dollarSign {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 61px;
  /* identical to box height */
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoText {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 39px;
  width: 395px;
  height: 59px;
  color: white;
}

.logoName {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 59px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoName:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  background-origin: 0px 5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
  transition: 1s;
}

.logoName:not(:hover) {
  transition: 1s;
}

.selected-lang {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.selected-lang-img {
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.triangle {
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 116px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-top: 7px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 6.5px;
}

.lang-menu {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.languages {
  position: absolute;
  left: 803.5px;
  top: 50px;
}

.lang-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 108px;
  padding-right: 38px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3s);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.lang-menu ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: 34px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.lang-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 108px;
}

.lang-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.lang-menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.lang-menu:hover ul {
  transition: 1s;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Предприниматели Казахстана</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="navigation">
      <img src="images/Cities.png" alt="Cities" class="cities" />
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="round">
          <p class="dollarSign">$</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logoText">
          <p class="logoName">ENTERPRENEUR.KZ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="languages">
        <div class="lang-menu">
          <div class="selected-lang">
            Язык:
            <img class="selected-lang-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/MCXYQD1/russia.png"/>
            <div class="triangle"></div>
          </div>
          <ul class="bgLang">
            <li>
              <a><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SyxxBx8/kazakhstan.png" alt="KZ" width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a><img src="https://i.ibb.co/rbcBCtd/united-kingdom.png" alt="UK" width="30px" height="30px" /></a>
            </li>
           
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Конец navigation -->
  </header>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: На стили особого внимания не обращал, если хотите увидеть результат, открывайте всю страницу

Comment: Спасибо большое! всё прекрасно работает, не подскажите как еще сделать так, чтобы и язык на сайте менялся?

Comment: а сколько страниц у вас на сайте

Comment: Если 3-4 можете создать статичные файлы (ru-index.html, en-about.html), но если много то советую использовать i18n или [Static Site Generators](https://jamstack.org/generators/) Next.js

Comment: Страниц немного, спасибо воспользуюсь вашим методом со статичными файлами